# Are Backpack views still in use?

Tags: view, laravel-backpack

Views are mentioned on the github docs [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Generators#usage), but I do not see them detailed on the Backpack tutorial docs [here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/getting-started-basics).

I created a view using `backpack:view Product`, but am not sure where it was put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using laravel 7 and backpack 4.1 and you can still use this command `php artisan backpack:view {Entity_name}`
I've tried this and laravel create the view in `resources/views` folder.